# How to set twitter bootstrap modal wider and higher?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, size, bootstrap-modal

How to set twitter bootstrap modal wider and higher?

Example here (please click: Launch demo modal):

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If your modal id is "myModal "

You could try adding a style like:

```
#myModal 
{
    width: 700px; 
    margin-top: -300px !important;
    margin-left:  -350px !important; 
} 

#myModal .modal-body {
    max-height: 525px;
}
```

Comment: #myModal: style="width:700px; margin: -250px 0 0 -525px;" tabindex="-1"  AND .modal-body: style="max-height: 525px;" How to set my modal in the middle of the screen? (now it is on the left)

Comment: Updated! Calculate approximately half the width... margin: -300px 0px 0px -350px .

Answer (score 56):

In [Bootstrap 3.1.1](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes) they added `modal-lg` and `modal-sm` classes. You control the `modal` size using `@media` queries like they do. This is a more global way of controlling the `modal` size.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .modal-lg {
        width: 900px;
        height: 900px; /* control height here */
    }
}
```

Sample code:

```
<!-- Large modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Small modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Small modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was good, except you need to put brackets after the media query in the CSS.

Comment: Hello, why not target directly the class .modal-dialog ?

Comment: But maybe `modal-lg` mast be added to div with class `modal` and not to `modal-dialog`? Because, I am using Bootstrap 3.3.5 and only when I add `modal-lg` to `div.modal` I get larger modal automatically (without additional styling).

Comment: @BohdanKuts please check again.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to do this is to use the .modal-lg. Add it to the modal-dialog class within the modal container like so:

```
<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                I am now wider!
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

For a size in %, you could do this:

```
.modal-body
{
   max-height:80%;
}
.modal
{
   height:80%;
   width:70%;
   margin-left: -35%; 
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
   .modal
   {
    width:90%;
        margin-left: 2%; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

altering class model-dialog did the trick for me

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your css file, add a new class definition:

```
.higherWider {
    width:970px;
    margin-top:-250px;
}
```

In your HTML, add `higherWider` inside the class string for your modal:

```
<div class="modal hide fade higherWider">
```

Comment: I do not believe margin-top is the solution, perhaps you mispeled for margin-left

Comment: No, the margin-top definition moves the element higher on the page, as indicated by naming the class "higherWider".

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer works well, however I would recommend using padding rather than margin. This way you retain the dismiss functionality when you click outside of the modal dialog.

```
#myModal {
    width: 700px; 
    padding-top: -300px !important;
    padding-left: -350px !important; 
} 

#myModal .modal-body {
    max-height: 525px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

css:

```
.modal-lg, .modal-sm {
    min-width: 90%;
}
```

code:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                Modal body..
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With CSS:

```
.modal {
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: -450px; // half of the width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works without viewport breakpoints and also for older bootstrap modals:

```
#myModal{
   position: fixed;
   left: 10% !important;
   right: 10% !important;
   top: 10% !important;
   width: 80% !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Either of the following solutions worked for me:

1. Applying `style="width: 50%; height:50%;"` to the `div` in the modal section with the `class="modal-dialog"` like so

   ```
   <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 50%; height:50%;">
   ```

   or
2. Creating a style section like so

   ```
    #themodal .modal-dialog{ width:50%; height:50%;}
   ```